# Как завернуть весь трафик в туннель, кроме 1 порта?

Tags: linux, iptables

Установил на VPS OpenVPN и завернул весь трафик в туннель для получения белого IP.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DNAT --to 10.8.0.2
```

Но и ssh тоже туда ушел. Как сформировать правило, чтобы ssh остался на хосте xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx?

Answer (score 0):

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ! --dport 22 -j DNAT --to 10.8.0.2